# "Join" existing socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Is it possible to create a socket connection (from either Python or a `nc` based listener), and then 'join' it from another Python process, sending data from the same socket to the same remote, and vice versa?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @Mike Does this require any special methods, or can I create a socket as normal?

Comment: No it does not require any special methods but you would need a module called "socket" You will also need other info like Ports and IPs

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a Python process to create a listening socket, `bind()` it to a port, and `listen()`s for incoming TCP connections on that port, and then at some point after that, another Python process can `connect()` to that port, at which point the first process can `accept()` the incoming TCP connection and the two processes can send data to each other over it.  So if that is what you are asking about, the Python [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module has the APIs you are looking for.

If OTOH you are asking about splicing a third party in as a middleman between two existing processes that are already communicating with each other over TCP, that is not possible without some serious low-level hackery, since TCP was designed as a 1-to-1 communications mechanism only.

Comment: I have a local port from one Python process with an existing connection to a remote service. Is it possible for a second process to also send data to the remote over the same connection, or does this fall under the low-level part of what you’re saying?

Comment: You could modify your Python process to act as a sort of proxy and forward the information to and/or from a second TCP connection to the other process.  If you wanted to do it without modifying your Python process, that would require low-level hackery.   (it might be simpler to just have the second process connect to the remote service directly, the same way the first process does, if that's an option)